# php xpath get node where attribute equals

Tags: php

I have an xml how can I get the node in `levelone` that has an attribute called `myatt` whose value is `a` and then access it's `myval`.
I tried referencing other posts to make it work but it doesn't seem to work what's wrong with my xpath

`$this->myXmlObj->xpath("//levelone[myfield[attributes/myatt='a]]]"));`

```
<myxml>
  <levelone>
      <myfield myatt="a" myval="aa" />
      <myfield myatt="b" myval="bb" />

  </levelone>  
  <leveltwo>
      <myfield myatt="c" myval="dd" />
      <myfield myatt="c" myval="dd" />
  </leveltwo>
</myxml>
```

### edit 1

```
array
  0 => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[41]
      public '@attributes' => 
        array
          'myval' => string 'a' (length=40)
```

### edit 2

```
    $myVar = $this->myXmlObj->xpath("//levelone/myfield[@myatt='a']");
    $myOutput = ((string)$myVar[0]->attributes()->myVal;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attributes in XPATH are referenced with `@attr` syntax.  So, you could retrieve `aa` with the following xpath

> //levelone/myfield[@myatt='a']/@myval

Which means, grab all `myfield` elements that have attribute `myatt` equal to `'a'`.  Then, from those, select the value of their `myval` attributes. Note that this could be multiple results.

A handy place to test XPATH expressions is at http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm.

Comment: skabbes thanks so much that works for matching the node but i'm not getting the value as a string i'm getting a structure still  (see edit 1)

Comment: @user391986, SimpleXML will only return elements from XPath queries, regardless of whether you ask for an attribute, string, number, etc. in the query.

Comment: I see thanks so should I do like in edit2 or is there a better way to extract the value?

Comment: I assume you're using [DOMXPath->query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php), in which case you'll need to pull the attribute out with $xpathResult->nodeValue.  You could also use [DOMXPath->evaluate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) instead.